# Difference between compressed and uncompressed kernel image written in the SPI flash RAM

Tags: u-boot

Is there any difference between compressed and uncompressed kernel image written or flashed into the flash RAM with U-Boot loader? I have an embedded system that has 4MB capacity SPI flash RAM and then one option I'm thinking is a compressed (lzma or gzip) kernel image which is about 1.6MB in size while the other option is using an uncompressed kernel image which is about 3.7MB? Will it be the same consumption in the flash RAM? Which one is more practical and suitable to use?

Comment: don't use lzma or gzip. They're terrible. Use zstd instead, or at least lz4. They're far better at speed and compression ratio

Comment: U-boot ? U-**B**oot ! ;-)

Comment: @phuclv decompression speed rarely matters when the memory you're talking to is as slow as early-stage flash. So, I'd argue, using lzma isn't the worst idea.